# Qt Remote Object - Do some requests at same time to a server

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, pyqt, qtremoteobjects

I use the qt remote object to transfer data between my server and my client. When my client do two calls at the same time to my server, my server it's not able to respond two response at the same time.

In my server, I have this code :

```
AService aService; 
BService bService;

QRemoteObjectHost srcNode(QUrl("tcp://" + (QString) "ipOfServer" + ":serverPort"));
srcNode.enableRemoting(&aService);
srcNode.enableRemoting(&bService);
```

My question is, How to put each call to my server on a separate thread. So, if my server receive a call for the aService and a call to the bService, each call is runned on a separate thread.

In the qt documentation, I find nothing on multi threading the QRemoteObjectHost, anyone have an issue ?